# For Loops in Windows Batch files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have some for loop code in a Windows Batch file for youtube-dl which looks like the following:

```
for %%a in (%*) do (
.\youtube-dl.exe ^
%%a ^
--playlist-start 1
timeout /t 300
)
```

I then put this code in a batch file named something.bat and pass in the URL as a variable:

```
something.bat ^
URL1 ^
URL2
```

This enables me the put the above code into another batch file somethingbatch.bat and call it directly for my batch file to run.

I would like to be able to change the argument for --playlist start dynamically, passed in as a parameter together with the URL. Is there any way that can be done, and if so, how would the code need to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first change the batch file like this:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (%*) do set ps=%%a
for %%a in (%*) do (
.\youtube-dl.exe ^
%%a ^
--playlist-start %ps%
timeout /t 300
)
```

Then call it like:

```
SomethingBat.bat ^
Url1 ^
Url2 ^
UrlN ^
PlaylistStart
```

You can specify the URLs first then specify value for PlaylistStart at last.

Comment: That's nice for my use case, thanks! Just 1 more follow up, if I wanted to do URL 1 +  ps1, URL 2 + ps2, URL 3 + ps3... etc, would it be possible?